# IE Version Checks are not working in Internet Explorer 8 on Some Computers

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, doctype

Internet Explorer Version Checks are not working in Internet Explorer 8 on Some Computers. Kindly Help.
DocType used are

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<![endif]-->
```

Browser Check used are

```html
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="scripts/js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="scripts/css/structie8.css" />
<![endif]-->


<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
j$(document).ready(function(){
  j$(".table tr:odd").css("background-color","#d4d4d4");
  j$(".table tr:even").css("background-color","#e2e2e2");
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Thanks

Comment: All three of those IE checks are exactly the same. If you are targeting specifically IE8 then `<!--[if IE 8]>` should suffice.

Comment: This <!--[if IE 8]>  did not work even.  so Kindly suggest something else.

Comment: Both should work if you are using IE8. If you are using IE specific CSS make sure it isn't being overwritten by the default CSS.

Comment: This also does not work. We are using IE8 through Developer Tools in IE 11. Thanks Please suggest something else.

Comment: "IE8 through Developer Tools in IE 11" is not IE8, especially when it comes conditional comments. Try in a real IE8.

Comment: Unfortunately unless you can use IE8 not a simulated version of IE8 this will not work.